# Для чего используются CFI-directives

Tags: ассемблер

Добрый день, уважаемые гуру, у меня такой вопрос. Дизассемблировал программку, написанную на C++ и получил такой код:

```
    ...
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $968, %rsp
    movq    %rdi, -1088(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -1096(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
    movq    -1096(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    ... // и т.д.
```

Для чего в ней стоят .cfi и как они используются? Почему во время отладки gdb пропускает эти строчки? 
Назначение директив смотрел [здесь](http://sources.redhat.com/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html), но смысл понять не могу

Comment: Спасибо, @alexlz, переформируйте пожалуйста ваш комментарий в ответ и я приму его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл сказал, что вопрос задавался на stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529185/what-are-cfi-directives-in-gnu-assembler-gas-used-for Там есть отрывок с http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-gnutool/

На ответ оно, по-моему, не тянет, но преобразовал